Why does "fine an instrument" feel like an article placed in between words?
Here is the dialogue from Emma (2020):

And have you heard the choicest piece of gossip that has set all the
tongues of the village aflame? A pianoforte, very elegant, delivered
to Miss Fairfax this very morning with no return address. I never saw
so fine an instrument.

Why does "fine an instrument" feel like an article placed in between words?

It's an old-fashioned, formal form - so adjective article noun I never saw so pretty a girl; I never heard so lovely a tune; I have seldom eaten so delicious a meal; I never want to see so ugly a toad again.

You have misparsed the phrase.  I never saw so fine an instrument = I never saw an an instrument that is so fine.

In my mid-Atlantic AmE dialect the construction is still used nowadays. It's not all that old-fashioned a way of talking.

TimR's comments notwithstanding, nearly all native speakers today would say I never saw such a fine instrument rather than I never saw so fine an instrument. You'll normally only encounter the so [adj] a [noun] form in literary/ poetic texts. Note that such a [adj] [noun] is generally more "flexible" anyway, because you can say things like I wish I had such a high quality instrument, but I wish I had so high quality an instrument is just weird.

@FumbleFingers.  It's not so big a deal.   I think you're getting caught up with the word "fine" and not realizing that this construction is very well established in contemporary English.

@TimR: I'm hardly being thrown by fine, since I went out of my way to illustrate my point with the far more "relaxed conversation" alternative high quality. Taking a more extreme line in that general direction, learners only need to consider I've never seen such a class act (perfectly natural), where I suggest I've never seen so class an act may never have been written or uttered until this very comment. Unless the learner aspires to become as fluent as actual native speakers, surely he should focus on the forms that have most general applicability.

You're bringing in so red a herring with "class act" ( a set phrase) that I don't know how to respond, other than to point out that "so classy an act" does work.

The mechanics of the construction are like this:
{phrase of degree} {adjective}{indefinite article}{noun phrase}

I cannot afford {so} {expensive} {a} {bicycle}.
Moreover, that carbon-fiber bike has been in a crash. I would never get back onto {so}{risky}{a}{bicycle}.
-- I don't worry about it. This bike has been through quite a few spills. It's not {all that}{risky}{a}{ride}.
Well, I don't care {however}{many}{a}{tumble} you've taken and are still here to tell the tale, I'm not buying that bike from you.

